# Saving FB Img with Parse

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, parse-platform

I am trying to save some of the current users information pulled from Facebook and save it to my parse database. I am successfully saving the name, but am having a lot of issues saving the photo. Here is my code:

```
 FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me",
                        parameters: ["fields": "id, name,friends, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, gender,taggable_friends"])
                        .startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                    print(String(result["picture"]))
                    PFUser.currentUser()!["name"] = String(result["name"])      

                    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(result["picture"])
                    let imageFile = PFFile(name:"image.png", data:imageData)

                    PFUser.currentUser()?["imageFile"] = imageFile
                    PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
                    })
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to save the image only once (without refreshing it when the user change it in Facebook) please follow JVS answer. If you want that the image will be changed each time the user change it on Facebook you can save the user Facebook ID in a specific column and then construct the URL of fetching the image in the client.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I was doing it in my completion handler:

```
let userId:String = result.objectForKey("id") as! String
let facebookProfilePictureUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?type=large"
let url = String(facebookProfilePictureUrl)
```

Now with the `URL` you can do the following:

```
if let fbpicURL = NSURL(string: facebookProfilePictureUrl) {

   if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: fbpicURL) {

      let imageFile:PFFile = PFFile(data: data)!


      PFUser.currentUser()?["imageFile"] = imageFile

      PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I don't use the image in my graphPath.